# ColorSpectrum Width and Height can't be Changed in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

```
ColorSpectrum ColorSpectrum = new ColorSpectrum();
ColorSpectrum.Width = 400;
ColorSpectrum.Height = 180;
```

But the Width and height cant be changed..How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the Width and height cant be changed..How to change it?

Unfortunately, the default shape of  `ColorSpectrum` is [square](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/color-picker#configure-the-color-picker), because a user will has more control when they select a specific color using a **square** because more of the color gamut is shown. So ColorSpectrum will limit by the minimum value of Width Height . If you want change the size, please set Width and Height same value.

```
ColorSpectrum ColorSpectrum = new ColorSpectrum();
ColorSpectrum.Width = ColorSpectrum.Height = 400;
```